# Code examples, like in the TikZ/PGF manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

I like very much the 'side-by-side' code examples in the TikZ/PGF manual...

[image]

... and I would like to use the same thing in a manual I'm writing. I have found the source code for the `codeexample` environment that the TikZ/PGF manual uses for this purpose (specifically, it's located at `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/macros/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex`).

My (probably rather basic) question is: how can I use the same `codeexample` environment in my own documents? I ask because I tried compiling the example in the related question below, but the file couldn't be found.

- [Automatic linking (aka code highlight) in Till Tantau's `codeexample`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33946/automatic-linking-aka-code-highlight-in-till-tantaus-codeexample)

Comment: Do you need all the bells and whistles of `codeexample` like highlighted text and background color, or would a verbatim solution suffice?

Comment: You can refer to [Is there a listings configuration for TikZ as used in PGF/TikZ manual?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72999/13304) where Christian explains exactly how to use the side-by-side environments, but there's also [tkzexample](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file/19942#19942).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks, I think `tkzexample` is exactly what I want. (I should have looked more thoroughly before asking my question!)

Comment: @JohnWickerson: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here, I use `tcolorbox` to resemble the visual appearance of the TikZ examples. The mandatory parameter of my example environment `sidebyside` is the width of the picture.

**Update:**
The first two examples use an automated invisible `tikzpicture` environment to display only a code snippet. The third example uses and displays the `tikzpicture` environment deliberately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\lstdefinestyle{example}{style=tcblatex,
  classoffset=0,
  texcsstyle=*\color{blue},%
  deletetexcs={begin,end},
  moretexcs={,%
    pgfdeclarehorizontalshading,pgfuseshading,node,
    useasboundingbox,draw}%
  classoffset=1,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  morekeywords={tikzpicture,shade,fill,draw,path,node,child,line,width,rectangle},
  classoffset=0}

\tcbset{%
  fillbackground/.style={before lower pre={%
  \tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at end picture={\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \fill[yellow!25!white]
    ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]current bounding box.south west) rectangle
    ([xshift=1mm,yshift=1mm]current bounding box.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}}}}}},
  explicitpicture/.style={before lower=\begin{center},after lower=\end{center},fillbackground}}

\newtcblisting{sidebyside}[2][]{%
  enhanced,frame hidden,
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  colback=blue!25!white,
  listing style=example,
  sidebyside,text and listing,text outside listing,sidebyside gap=2mm,
  lefthand width=#2,tikz lower,fillbackground,
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidebyside}[before lower app={\path[] (-2,-0.5) rectangle (2,0.5);}]{4.2cm}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingA}
  {1cm}{rgb(0cm)=(1,0,0); color(2cm)=(green); color(4cm)=(blue)}
\pgfuseshading{myshadingA}
\end{sidebyside}

\begin{sidebyside}{4.2cm}
\node {root}
  child {node {left}}
  child {node {right}
    child {node {child}}
    child {node {child}}
};
\end{sidebyside}

\begin{sidebyside}[explicitpicture]{4.2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=20pt]
  \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw[gray,->] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{sidebyside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to also highlight the backslash symbol as well?

Comment: @KevinC Yes. Here, the `listings` package does the formatting job in the background. The settings are made by `\lstdefinestyle` in my example code. I edited the example to add the backslash highlighting. I also changed the third example to display an explicit `tikzpicture` environment as in the TikZ manual.